# Cache not working on client for JSON response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, caching

I have a method that return a complex JSON object. It's a heavy processing method which i'm trying to store it on cache and leave it there until a modification is done on it's objects.

```
[HttpPost]
[OutputCache(Duration=50, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client, VaryByParam="none", NoStore = false)]
        public ActionResult CacheTest()
        {
            //retrieves data from database
            var data = DBContext.GetUserLog();

            return Json(new { userLog = data});
        }
```

Setting `Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client` and `VaryByParam = 'none'` is not working. If i set `Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient` the response is correctly cached.

Any reasons why OutputCache doesn't store JSON information on client side?

Comment: Client site storage (cookies and local storage) are limited in terms of the amount of data they can hold. Do you want this to persist after each request or just while the user is on the page?

Comment: It would be nice to persist after any amount of requests but with on a limited time. However, i can manage it to stay on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC POST requests are not cached on the client. This verb is intended to be used when you are modifying state on the server which you don't seem to be doing. If you are returning some values from the server without modifying state use GET instead.

Comment: Didn't know that. So if i change the verb to GET, client side is supposed to cache the results right? I've just did some tests here and even though i can see that Cache-Control has changed to private from no cache and max-age to 200, the page is not cached on client side. Anything else i should do?

Comment: I did more tests i could see notice that even though `Cache-Control: max-age` doesn't change, the results still get cached. I'm not sure why i can't see how long lasts cache on client side before expiration.